# continued... grep -c gives inconsistent outputs

Tags: grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grep -c gives inconsistent outputs](https://superuser.com/questions/342051/grep-c-gives-inconsistent-outputs)

I am trying to determine the number of processes that are running via the following command line:

```
ps aux | grep -c 'Xvfb :1'
```

When the process "fiji :1" is not running I sometimes get a value of 0 and other times a value of 1.  The act of running the grep command seems to be counted sometimes and other times not.

Running the command line below gives consistently zero processes:

```
ps aux | grep 'fiji :1' | grep -v grep
```

Similar to adding the `grep -v grep`, is there a way to make "grep -c" count the number of processes running minus the grep command?

```
ps aux | grep Xvfb gives this:

60293 17250 0.0 0.1 45052 7016 pts/4 S Sep30 0:02 Xvfb :4 -screen 0 1600x1200x16 
60293 17373 0.0 0.0 40704 2964 pts/0 S Sep30 0:02 Xvfb :5 -screen 0 800x600x16 
60293 29695 0.0 0.1 42996 6112 pts/6 S 13:00 0:00 Xvfb :3 -screen 0 1600x1200x16 
60293 31650 0.0 0.0 61160 756 pts/6 R+ 13:58 0:00 grep Xvfb
```

`pgrep 'Xvfb :3' | wc -l` doesn't quite work because it returns 0 when there is actually 1 process running.

`pgrep 'Xvfb' | wc -l` returns 3 which is correct.

I also tried `pgrep 'Xvfb :3 -screen 0 1600x1200x16' | wc -l` and it incorrectly returned 0.

Seems like `pgrep` doesn't like the space in `Xvfb :3`?